# Find exact match in list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

very new to this so bear with me please...

I got a predefined list of words

```
checklist = ['A','FOO']
```

and a words list from `line.split()` that looks something like this

```
words = ['fAr', 'near', 'A']
```

I need the exact match of `checklist` in `words`, so I only find 'A':

```
if checklist[0] in words:
```

That didn't work, so I tried some suggestions I found here:

```
if re.search(r'\b'checklist[0]'\b', line):
```

To no avail, cause I apparently can't look for list objects like that... Any help on this?

Comment: regex is overkill here when you can loop over array and check if the element is in the predefined array.

Comment: `checklist[0]` _is_ `in words`. Can you be more specific about how it "didn't work"?

Comment: So what do you want to do? What do you mean about *Find exact match in list of strings?*

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, will formulate more clearly next time around. Stress. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you a list of exact matches.

`matches = [c for c in checklist if c in words]`

Which is the same as:

```
matches = []
for c in checklist:
  if c in words:
    matches.append(c)
```

Comment: This will not return exact matches, it will also return partial matches.

Comment: This answer is correct for returning partial matches not exact matches

Comment: @A.M what do you mean "partial matches"?

Comment: @pushkin, Partial matches means if you have a list `a = ['FOO', 'FOOL', 'A', 'B']` and looking for only string FOO in the list, your code appends both FOO and FOOL to the matches list, which means your code append both exact match ('FOO') and partial match ('FOOL') and the question is 'Find exact match in list of strings'   :)

Comment: @A.M I don't believe that's the case. I'm doing string `in` a list. That will return exact matches (see [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/in-and-not-in-operators-in-python)). `in` will do a substring match if `words` in my code were itself a string. I just ran this code and it returned only exact matches

Comment: @JimArcher What are you basing that off of? I just tried running code like `a = ["ab"];print("a" in a)`, and it returned `False`

Comment: Yes that does work, I was seeing opposite behavior the other day. When I have time I'll try to reproduce it. I'll take the comment down for now.

Comment: I also think this returns partial matches as I'm trying to find a solution to get exact matches, and the existing code that I have uses `in` and it returns partial matches.

Comment: @rksh are you able to post your code? In all my tests and prior experience, `in` only does partial matches when you're using it on a string. On array elements, it returns complete matches for me.

Answer (score 20):

Using a set would be much faster than iterating through the lists.

```
checklist = ['A', 'FOO']
words = ['fAr', 'near', 'A']
matches = set(checklist).intersection(set(words))
print(matches)  # {'A'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set will meet your needs. There is an `issubset` method of set. The example is like following:

```
checklist = ['A','FOO']
words = ['fAr', 'near', 'A']

print set(checklist).issubset(set(words))
```

If you only need test if there is comment element in two list, you could change to `intersection` method.

Comment: The set methods are really golden, if you have large data sets they are much much quicker than using for loops.

Comment: This method did not work. I gain "False" when I should get "True".

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you,

```
In [67]: test = re.match(r"(.*?)A(.*?)$", "CAT")
```

In [68]: test.group(2)

Out[68]: 'T'

In [69]: test.group()

Out[69]: 'CAT'

In [70]: test.group(1)

Out[70]: 'C'

If the pattern in does not match, the test object does not exists.